# How can I upload what I've designed in visual studio back to office 365 server?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint

I adquired an office 365 for developers server to publish web pages with sharepoint, I installed napa and it gave me the option of working in visual studio, after doing some work I don't know now how to upload back the files to the sharepoint server, it didn't upload automatically and I don't know whats wrong.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: did you solved your problem? because I'm facing the same issue too

Comment: Not really, sorry, I ended up using a virtual machine instead of sharepoint 365.

Answer (score 0):

**Using "Napa" Office 365 Development tools**

1. Add "Napa" Office 365 Development Tools from the SharePoint Store to your developer site.
2. Click on Napa on the Site Contents page
3. Add New Project
4. Various apps will be available for your choosing.  Select App for SharePoint. Give the app a name and click "Create"
   [image]
5. Within the Napa window, develop your new app
   [image]
6. Click Run Project to deploy your app to your Office 365 Preview

[image]

7. Your project is being packaged and installed on your SharePoint Server

[image]

you can read more about this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2012/07/17/introducing-napa-office-365-development-tools.aspx)

Comment: Hi, but using Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio, how can I upload my visual studio code to the napa window? it doesn't alow me to upload .cs files directly and I'm missing so much!

Comment: Hi Ana - I have updated all the steps above, do let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Hi Sat, thanks for your answer, what I'm missing is if you see the second button next to the run project icon, you can download your code to visual studio and edit it there, after you finished, how can you upload the code you modified back?